# How can i set the boundary for multipart request in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I need to send a multipart document to a server. IT seems however that the server expects the boundary to be a specific sequence "************". If I use multipart request, it seems to default to something else even when I add a request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed missing in the current version of Codename One (didn't expect people would need functionality like this).

We will add a `setBoundary(String)` method for the next update in 3 weeks or so.

Comment: ok. solved my problem by modifying multipart directly and setting the boundary to what i want.